# Modify html within Iframe, using the users input

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an HTML page within an iframe on another page. The main page has a text area for a user to change the title text on the page inside of the iframe. What I am trying to do is have the user be able to enter the title he wants in the text area, and have that input displayed in the  iframe html code. 
What I don't know how to do use take a user input from one page, and input it into another page. Any help on how to do this or a point in the right direction would be helpful

Comment: Are they both on the same domain?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to pass a query string parameter from page 1 and reload the source of the iframe used inside it. On the other page, get the query string parameter and use it to change the property of the html element.

Here's a sample code :

**Page 1 :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>This is page 1</h2>
    <input type="text" onchange="ChangeText(this);" />
    <iframe id="ifrm1" src="HtmlPage2.html"></iframe>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         var originalUrl;
         $().ready(function () {
             originalUrl = $("#ifrm1").attr("src");
         });
         function ChangeText(obj) {             
             $("#ifrm1").attr("src", originalUrl + "?text=" + obj.value);
         }         

   </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

**Page 2 :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>This is page 2</h2>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" />
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $().ready(function ()
         {
             var getText = getParameterByName("text");
             $("#txt1").val(getText);
         });

         function getParameterByName(name) {
             name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
             var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                 results = regex.exec(location.search);
             return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
         }

   </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Looks like somebody didn't have balls to give an explaination on why the answer was marked down. COWARD.

Comment: i've given up on this ridiculous website, i'm now banned from asking any questions because this one was marked for no apparent reason. However, thanks for the answer